# How can I return a reference wrapped by `Option` by implementing `Deref` in Rust?

Tags: rust

I have a wrapper struct which stores an `Option` field. I would like to get a reference to the data stored in this field. The following code compiles.

```rust
struct Wrapper {
    val: Option<i32>
}

impl Wrapper {
    // lifetime specifier elided because Rust compiler can infer it
    // to be fn my_deref<'a>(&'a self) -> Option<&'a i32>
    fn my_deref(&self) -> Option<&i32> {
        self.val.as_ref()
    }
}
```

However, I prefer implementing `Deref` trait for `Wrapper`, so that I can have dereference coercion which is very nice. I tried the following code but the compiler complains.

```rust
use std::ops::Deref;
struct Wrapper {
    val: Option<i32>
}

impl Deref for Wrapper {
    type Target = Option<&i32>; // It tells me I need a lifetime specifier.
    fn deref(&self) -> Option<&i32> {
        self.val.as_ref()
    }
}
```

I then tried to add a lifetime specifier, but failed again.

```rust
use std::ops::Deref;
struct Wrapper<'a> { // It tells me 'a is never used.
    val: Option<i32>
}

impl<'a> Deref for Wrapper<'a> {
    type Target = Option<&'a i32>;
    fn deref(&'a self) -> Option<&'a i32> {
        self.val.as_ref()
    }
}
```

What is the correct way to implement `deref` that does the same thing as `my_deref`?

Comment: You cannot do that. The trait method `Deref::deref` returns a reference.

Comment: Implementing `Deref<Target = U>` for `T` does not mean that you can get a `U` from a `T`! It means that you can get an `&U` from an `&T`.  In this case, the new `Option` that is created by the `as_ref` call in the `deref` function is not the same `Option` that your `Wrapper` stores, and as such you can't return a reference to it.

Comment: @turbulencetoo that's true but the same can be said about `my_deref` function where `self.val.as_ref()` returns new `Option`. I guess then the main question is: how compiler correctly elided in case of `my_deref` but not `deref`?

Comment: The main problem isn't the elision, but the unconstrained lifetime parameter. It doesn't make sense to have `type Target = Option<&'a i32>;` because the `'a` comes out of nowhere.

Comment: I think I got it..So `&'a i32` (correctly elided) is allowed but not `&'a Option<&'b i32>`. That's because now we have new lifetime `'b` that compiler cannot elide. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading turbulencetoo's comment, I come up with the following code, which does exactly what I intend. By program logic the `Option` field will never be `None`, so I can safely unwrap it. I must use `Option` to wrap it for some other reason irrelevant to this topic.

```rust
use std::ops::Deref;
struct Wrapper {
    val: Option<i32>
}

impl Deref for Wrapper {
    type Target = i32;
    fn deref(&self) -> &i32 {
        self.val.as_ref().unwrap()
    }
}
```

Quoting turbulencetoo's comment below.

> Implementing Deref for T does not mean that you can get a U from a T! It means that you can get an &U from an &T. In this case, the new Option that is created by the as_ref call in the deref function is not the same Option that your Wrapper stores, and as such you can't return a reference to it.

Comment: You don't have to repeat the return type. I think it's better to use `fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target`. See https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html#examples

Comment: @SujitJoshi is there any extra benefit using `&Self::Target` rather than typing `&i32` again? `&i32` is shorter though lol.

Comment: Well...if you decide to change Target type...then you would have to search and replace. And depending on how complicated you `Deref` impl is that might not be easy. In that case...just changing Target is much easier.

Comment: If `val` is never `None`, why do you need to wrap it in an `Option`?

Comment: @SvenMarnach I use `Option` as a container. The object contained in `Option` is "moved" from other places. I also implement `Drop` for the wrapper struct, which is not shown in the code above. When the wrapper struct goes out of scope, I want the contained object to be automatically returned to its original place. But `drop()` takes a mutable reference to `self`, rather than owning `self`. I must encompass it into `Option` to let it be able to "move" back in `drop()` function.

Comment: @ZhiyaoMa Thanks for the explanation, I was genuinely curious. So it's not really "never" `None` – it's `None` towards the end of your `drop()` impl. If the wrapped type has a cheaply constructable default, you can also use `std::mem::replace()` to swap in the default.

Comment: @SvenMarnach You are right. And I choose to do that way exactly because constructing a new object of same type is expensive. :)

Comment: Another option would be `ManuallyDrop::take()`, but it's unstable and unsafe.